# Pass JSON Data From AJAX to PHP

Tags: php, json, ajax, variables, post

I have this function:

```
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../<?php echo $version; ?>/send_clients.php",
         data: { 
              'userID': '<?php echo $_COOKIE["userID"] ?>', 
              'token': '<?php echo $_COOKIE["token"] ?>'
                 },

        success: function (response) {
            if (response.indexOf("tokenError") > -1){
            location.replace("login.php");
          }else{
            console.log(response);

          }
        }
    });
```

Server return a JSON ("response").
How can I pass "response" value from this function to a php Array or Variable?
This function is in the same place of that I want to pass data

Comment: In short, you cant. PHP is a pre-processor. It renders the page. It can't receive anything afterwards. You could however pass whatever data to JavaScript arrays and process it from there.

Comment: Please clarify more of what you are going to do with that response data. Its not clear. You may have confused the entire flow of what you are trying to achieve.